# Alternative to mounting /dev/shm volume in Selenium Grid AWS Fargate setup

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-grid, aws-fargate, aws-ecs

Because AWS Fargate is stateless and does not currently support any sort of persistence (that I know of or was able to find), I am running into an issue with my Selenium Grid setup. When I had the grid running in Docker, I did what most people seem to be doing and mounted the /dev/shm volume of the node container to the host. Unfortunately this is not possible using Fargate. Has anyone figured out a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Currently AWS Fargate doesn't supports privileged mode and mounting of devices from underline docker host.

As of now there is no way to mount /dev/shm from docker host to container in Fargate.

It is advisable to use EC2 Launch type to support this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable dev_shm usage.

For Chrome you should use:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        ...
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```

and for Firefox please try to set the system environment variable:

set MOZ_FORCE_DISABLE_E10S=1

The drawback for FF is, that you will disable FF multiprocessing, however I do not think this is highly important for Selenium grid implementation. Just hope FF will preserve this feature or provide an alternative.

Background for the Chrome solution can be found here
[WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/50725918#50725918)

Background for the FF solution can be found here: 
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=3051846